# What is the $P(X=0)$ where $X$ is a random variable?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Given the probability mass function $f_X(x)=.1\delta(x)+.9u(x)e^{-x}$ find the probability that $P(X=0)$? I am a little bit confused with $\delta$ function. I know that if we have continuous random variable $P(X=a)=0$ for all $a$ values. So the probability in case of the given random variable would be zero. But $\delta(0)$ is 0.1. Can someone entangle this for me?

Comment: One of my books have a Lemma that says,

Comment: You find the probability not by plugging in $x$ to $f_X(x)$, but rather by integrating $f_X(x)$. So integrate it from $0$ to $0$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $\delta$ is the [Dirac delta impulse function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function).   This has the property $\int_\Bbb R \delta(x)\operatorname d x = 1$

Sometimes written as $\displaystyle\lim_{A\to\{0\}}\int_A \delta(x)\operatorname d x=1\;,\, \lim_{A\to\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}}\int_A \delta(x)\operatorname d x=0$

Similarly the Heaviside step function being used appears to be, $u(x) = \begin{cases} 1 &:& x>0\\0&:&x\leq 0\end{cases}$

Basically the use of $\delta$ and $u$ indicates that you have a mixture distribution, with a probability mass at a discrete point and a probability density elsewhere in the support.  (But where and how much?)

So what you are looking for is:

$$\mathsf P(X=0) =\lim_{A\to\{0\}}\int_A 0.1\delta(x)+0.9 u(x)e^{-x}\operatorname d x \color{white}{= 0.1}$$

Answer (score 2):

Your random variable $X$ is of *mixed* type https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Mixed_type , a nice compromise between a discrete and a continuous random variable. This means that it can take both continuous and discrete values: in this specific case, it can take the discrete value $X=0$ with probability $0.1$, and any real (continuous) value $x>0$, with probability $P(a<X<b)=0.9\int_a^b e^{-x}dx$.